# Get a list of the last opened text and odt files

Tags: bash, ubuntu, terminal, search

can I retrieve a list of the last opened textfiles (well, I have some textfiles without ending `.txt` which is probably not possible to retrieve. Some do have a .txt ending though) Also I need the last opened .odt files but thanks to session saving of Kubuntu these were more than LibreWriter itself shows under "file -> last opened files." So is there a way to search for something like `last_opened` with ending and to set the count of the files to be listed via terminal?

Thanks

Comment: Is the file system supporting your files mounted **atime** ? (I mean not **noatime** since atime is default)

Comment: I don't know. I guess it's ext3. How do I check?

Comment: Then add the output of cat /etc/fstab to your question.